# Where in the JellyBean android source tree is the Notifications Pull Down?

Tags: android-source

I am looking to implement a particular feature I saw in the notification drop-down, and I'd like to see the source code for it. Can anyone, preferably someone who hacks on the source, tell me where to look in these projects: https://github.com/android
John

Answer (score 0):

NotificationManagerService is responsible for showing notifications. It is situated in the `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java`. In your case I think you should look at [this link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java).

Comment: That is not the notification dropdown. That is the notification service that powers the notification drop down. I am looking for the drop down menu itself, and particularly its ListView implementation.

Comment: Can you show an example of this notification and/or code example how to use it?